# Apps Script Properties Service

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

All

I have a Google Sheet linked to a Google Form for data collection and apps script within sheets.I am assigning account numbers belonging to a specific range for every account type to every form submission such that nobody has same account numbers. 
I am using documentProperties to store a Key(account type), value(account number) pair in Google Apps script. Recently after few months of smooth functioning, I had to re-authorize the app script because I changed my password. Since then, all my documentProperties have been reset to default values and I am facing the issue of people getting assigned same account numbers.

Has this happened with someone else? I seek help from people who have used Properties Service feature of Google Apps Script.

Comment: This is a possible bug or a usage issue.  This is not the type of question that is "On Topic" for Stack Overflow.  You can post your question in the [Apps Script group](https://plus.google.com/communities/102471985047225101769)

Comment: I prefer using files to store my data.  I started doing this when I got a error on a properties parameter being to large.  I don't have to worry about that anymore.

Comment: Thanks Cooper for the suggestion. I guess there are a few issues with the PropertiesService therefore, just like you, I switched back to storing data in external Google Sheet.

Comment: I'm having similar issues for the past several weeks. I can no longer modify script properties on Apps Scripts that have been working for many months.This old post is the closet that I've seen which is similar to the problem I'm facing.